# How to integrate CRM with Outlook to track emails and threads?

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, integration, crm

If there's a more relevant Stack to post this question on, please let me know.

**Problem:**
We have an in-house built CRM which tracks Leads, Sales and Orders. Our users are interacting with customers via email in Outlook (Online).  These email communications contain important information that we want visible in our CRM. Currently, users will copy and paste email content and add them as notes into our CRM activities. The optimial solution would be that any email communications associated with the customer order are stored and visible in the CRM activity.

I know that many other CRMs have some type of integration with Outlook/Mail providers. My question is, how do they achieve this? I presume some would use an intermediate email gateway that is the middleman.

My thought process would be that a user can "opt" an email/thread into being tracked by the CRM.
The CRM is then able to track emails and replies (via Microsoft Graph using webhooks/CRON to endpoint), and copy them over into the CRM database for display.

Would love any links to resources, personal experience, or suggestions that would help me in understanding the best way to achieve this.

**In summary:**
Certain Email chains within Outlook can be "flagged" to be tracked and displayed in the corresponding CRM activity.

I have spent a few hours researching possible solutions, but the search engine keywords return irrelevant results.

Comment: I'm working on a project that downloads a lot of emails from multiple sources like Outlook, Gmail, custom server, etc. I think you should do the same thing and try to filter what you want from email and display it in your CRM. In this case, you can use Graph API to download the `eml` file and convert it to readable text before filtering.